Уже несколько минут не могу решить проблему связанную с циклом в PHP
Код такой:
foreach ($leads as $leadData) {
            $data = $leadData['data'];

            $dealForBus = json_encode([
                "ownerId" => $object->ownerId
            ]);
            addToBus($this->pdo, $event, $dealForBus);
        }

Данные внутри $leads такие:
[
        {
            "id": 53,
            "moment": "2024-07-15 21:27:53",
            "data": {
                "messageId": "3ABB9BBF9ACB92858E87"
            },
            "sourceData": {
                "messageId": "3ABB9BBF9ACB92858E87"
            }
        },{
            "id": 54,
            "moment": "2024-07-15 21:27:58",
            "data": {
                "messageId": "3ABB9BBF9ACB92858E87"
            },
            "sourceData": {
                "messageId": "3ABB9BBF9ACB92858E87"
            }
        }
]

Проблема заключается в том, что после итерации цикла значение id внутри leads меняется, то есть если например как приведенном мною случае внутри leads имеются id равные 53 и 54 то после прохождения через цикл, а именно после строки $data = $leadData['data']; значение id равный 54 заменяется на 53 и соответственно leads после этого имеет значения id 53 и 53. И каждый раз последний id заменяется на предыдущий.

Не ясна ни суть вопроса, ни то, почему вы вообще решили, что проблема на той конкретной строчке, где data потом вообще нигде не участвует

Попробуйте всё же начать с отладки ↑↑↑

Вообще то я использовал отладку и именно поэтому я уверен в том что проблема возникает в той строке которую я указал, вам бы стоило помочь если можете, а если не можете то пройти мимо

Да ни шиша вы не использовали.

Повторю: строчка $data = $leadData['data']; совершенно бессмысленна  и не участвует нигде в приведённом коде. Так что говорить о том, что именно там проблема, выявленная с помощью отладки - полная чепуха

ахах как таких неадекватов вообще в такие форумы пускают, я уже решил проблему, а тебе желаю разума

Спасибо, но вам это явно нужнее

Попробуйте поработать с циклом for:
for($i = 0; $i <= count($leads)-1; $i++){
   $leads_id = $leads[$i]["id"];
   $leads_moment = $leads[$i]["moment"];
   $leads_data_messageId = $leads[$i]["data"]["messageId"];
   $leads_sourceData_messageId = $leads[$i]["sourceData"]["messageId"];
   //Далее подставляем эти переменные в нужные функции
}

